# openvpn AS clients to be part of same subnet in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, amazon-vpc

is it possible that openvpn clients , can take IP address from VPC subnet (when they connect to vpn server?
Like i have setup an openvpn AS server. they have IP address 172.x.x.x/8 and if clients connect to openvpn server, can they get IP address in range of 172.x.x.x/8 ?

Actually i want that when a vpn client connect to vpn server, then other servers in VPC can also connect to the vpn client, without anything special done on their side

Comment: How many OpenVPN clients are there?  There is a way to assign addresses from the VPC to remote clients, but it's counter-intuitive and limited by the ENI limits on the instance type you are using as your OpenVPN server.

Comment: There is just 2 or even 1 client. but how can we assign IP ? can openvpn do it?

Comment: I will review the configuration I have used for this, before, and explain how it can be done, in an answer.  In my application, I used this to give native addresses from the VPC subnets to the machines in another provider's cloud... with OpenVPN.  The remote servers are openVPN clients.